# С начала суток часовая стрелка повернулась на угол в α градусов. Определите на какой угол повернулась минутная стрелка с начала последнего часа

Tags: python, алгоритм

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм решения данной задачи:

> С начала суток часовая стрелка повернулась на угол в α градусов.
>   Определите на какой угол повернулась минутная стрелка с начала
>   последнего часа. Входные и выходные данные — действительные числа.

Задача отсюда: [тут](http://pythontutor.ru/lessons/int_and_float/problems/watch_2/).
Написал 2 варианта решения, но работает не верно. Вот один из:

```
a = float(input())
m=int(a*2)%60
print(m*6)
```

Comment: опишите словами как работает ваш алгоритм, и почему вы считаете что работает не верно?

Comment: @Grundy, работает не верно в некоторых тестах, которые предлагает сайт. Я думаю так: нам известно отклонение часовой стрелки, значит кол-во часов мы отбрасываем и получаем кол-во минут. Если нарисовать - то одна минута равна 6 градусам минутной стрелки. Так я получаю отклонению минутной стрелки в градусах.

Comment: алгоритм в сам вопрос вставьте

Comment: @ВладиславМСК - Ваши три строчки кода не имеют ничего общего с Вашим описанием решения.

Comment: @Igor, как тогда написан этот код?

Comment: @ВладиславМСК - Откуда я знаю, что для Вас означает вот эта бессмыслица: "кол-во часов мы отбрасываем и получаем кол-во минут"? От чего Вы отбрасываете количество часов, и как в результате получается количество минут? Кто ясно мыслит - ясно излагает.

Comment: @Igor, я вас понял.

Answer (score 4):

Минутная стрелка движется в 12 раз быстрее часовой.
Один час - это поворот часовой стрелки на 30 градусов.

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <input type=number ng-model=angle ng-init="angle=0">
  <output>{{angle % 30 * 12}}</output>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

За час минутная стрелка совершает полный оборот (`1 круг == 360°`), а часовая стрелка передвигается на один час (`1/12 круга == 30°`). Поэтому полный угол поворота минутной стрелки в 12 раз больше, чем угол поворота часовой стрелки.

Угол поворота часовой стрелки с начала последнего часа это остаток от деления на `30`:

```
α = float(input('Угол поворота часовой стрелки: '))
print((α % 30) * 12)  # угол поворота минутной стрелки за последний час
```

Может быть проще запомнить формулу, если сперва преобразовать угол поворота часовой стрелки в угол поворота минутной стрелки (`α * 12`), а затем найти угол поворота минутной стрелки, который относится только к последнему часу — последнему обороту (`% 360` — один оборот это 360°) как предложил [@StateItPrimitive в комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506307/%d0%a1-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2-%ce%b1-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba#comment610256_506329):

```
α = float(input('Угол поворота часовой стрелки: '))
print((α * 12) % 360)  # угол поворота минутной стрелки за последний час
```

Игнорируя ошибки, относящиеся к вычислениям, использующим числа с плавающей точкой, результат обоих формул одинаковый.

Answer (score 0):

1. За сутки часовая стрелка поворачивается на 720 градусов, то есть за час на 30.
2. За час минутная стрелка поворачивается на 360 градусов
3. Получаем пропорцию (на C# - pithon не знаю)

   ```cs
   int dHH = alpha%30;

   double degMM = dHH/30. * 360;
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас перепишу. Но я не понимаю, почему отталкиваемся от суток? На часах 12 часов -> 360/12 = 30 градусов.
И что даст пропорция?

Comment: @ВладиславМСК мы получаем количество градусов, которые проходит часовая стрелка за один час, чтобы в дальнейшем отсеять сдвиг часовой стрелки за все часы, кроме последнего, что необходимо для вашего условия, т.к. там сказано "с начала последнего часа"

Comment: использовать `int` здесь неправильно (результат не обязан быть целым, например, если `alpha=15.1`, то результат должен быть `181.2`, а не `180`.

Comment: @jfs, а вы увкрены, что стрелка может повернутся на 1,2 градуса?

Comment: @Mirdin это разумный вопрос, но который не имеет отношения к задаче в вопросе. Если вы хотите решать(не относящуюся к вопросу) физическую задачу, то первый вопрос должен быть с какой точностью угол часовой стрелки измеряется.

Comment: @jfs - Обычно 6 градусов. Но я не о том, просто спорить о точности... имеет смысл, только если точность задана условием задачи.

Comment: В задаче явно указано: ввод/вывод — действительные числа. `int` здесь не следует использовать.

Answer (score 0):

А можно подойти так: узнать разность между всем углом, который прошла минутная стрелка (в 12 раз быстрее, т.е. `a*12`) и углом, до начала ближайшего часа `(a*12//360)*360`. Небольшая ремарка: будьте внимательны, оператор `//` возвращает целое от деления, поэтому сокращать ничего не нужно.

Comment: Т.е. исходя из вашей формулы, получается, что если в ней сократить числитель и знаменатель, то нужно просто умножить на 12 (`a*12`)? Это точно не верно, а вот `a%30 * 12` уже совсем другое дело.

Comment: Я прошу прощения, не очень понял что сокращать в моей формуле. `a*12` это полный угол, который прошла минутная стрелка. Из этого полного угла вычитаем угол, который прошла минутная стрелка до ближайшего часа и получаем ответ. Всегда можно проверить на задаче: `a=float(input())
print(a*12-(a*12//360)*360)`

Comment: Я вот про эту часть: `(a*12//360)*360`, тут идет деление на 360 и тут же умножение снова на 360 (или я чего-то конкретно не понимаю).

Comment: В python `//` оператор целочисленного деления..

Comment: Это сильно меняет дело! Извиняюсь за свое незнание синтаксиса _python_, но на первый взгляд все же, если идти по вашей логике, то ответ должен быть чуть проще: `(a*12)%360`, разве нет? Получаем угол, который прошла минутная стрелка, а затем отсекаем все часы, кроме последнего (ну, просто ваш через целую часть от деления, а тут через остаток).

Comment: Ваш ответ, конечно, верен. Но, как по мне, мой вариант больше подходит для объяснения _на пальцах_. В общем, дискутировать об этом можно ещё очень долго)

Comment: @ВитяАлександрович: ответ неверный потому что результат у вас всегда целое число. Очевидно, что большую часть времени угол поворота минутной стрелки не является целым числом. Вероятно вы хотели `(a * 12) % 360` формулу вместо вашей `(a*12//360)*360`

Answer (score 0):

```
h = float(input('hour gradus: '))

min = ((h%30)*6)*2

print(min)
```